# VBA editing registry Trusted Locations *sometimes* works

Tags: excel, vba, registry

I am attempting to add locations to the trusted location list in the registry for Excel while installing some add-ins and macro-enabled workbooks to user computers.  The theory is that the users will run the install one time, and the program will set everything up for them so that they do not see any trust warnings or accidentally disable the code because they "X" out of the security warning banner when the workbook is opened. First, I check to see if the user add-in folder is trusted; if not, then it is added to the list.  This part works every time that I've tested.  Then, a user-selected folder is added, based on where the user chooses to install the workbooks.  This part never works.  The code is exactly the same for the two iterations, but it only works on the first "Location".  Removing a lot of the fluff from the install program, the critical parts boil down to this:

```
Const HCU = &H80000001      ' HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
ver = Application.Version
AIPath = Application.UserLibraryPath
regKey = "Software\Microsoft\Office\" & ver & "\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations\"

oReg.EnumKey HCU, regKey, SubKeys

For n = 0 To UBound(SubKeys)
    oReg.GetStringValue HCU, regKey & SubKeys(n), "Path", rPath
    If rPath = AIPath Then Exit For
Next

If n > UBound(SubKeys) Then
    regLoc = "Location" & CStr(n)
    oReg.CreateKey HCU, regKey & regLoc
    oReg.SetStringValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "Path", AIPath
    oReg.SetStringValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "Description", "User add-in folder"
    oReg.SetStringValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "Date", CStr(Now)
    oReg.setDWORDValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "AllowSubFolders", 1
End If


regLoc = "Location" & CStr(n + 1)
objReg.CreateKey HCU, regKey & regLoc
objReg.SetStringValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "Path", UsrPath
objReg.SetStringValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "Description", "Price Calc folder"
oReg.SetStringValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "Date", CStr(Now)
objReg.setDWORDValue HCU, regKey & regLoc, "AllowSubFolders", 1
```

I realize that there is a bit of a logical hole in the Location(n/n+1) parameter, if the current list happens to skip Location #s for some reason.  However, that does not occur on the machine I'm using to test, so it should not cause a problem here.  Yet every time I run this, I end up with the key for  Location7 = "C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Addins" and the key for Location8 not existing at all.  I have directly used the Excel Trust Center to set my test user folder to a trusted location, so it's not something that is prohibited by the system or security settings.

When I test the program, I can step through and see that it executes each of the statements, but checking the registry shows that only the first registry key is actually created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as silly as it was, the key here was the order of operations.  In moving the different sections of my code around, I had actually put the reg-edit *before* the target folder got created.  After the code ran and the folder was created, I could go through the Excel Trust Center and make it a Trusted Location.  Before the folder is actually there, the lines will execute but the registry key will not be created because no target exists.  The first iteration to add a registry key worked every time because the user add-in folder was always there.

The original code works, if anyone is trying to do this. It is adapted from a few other sources (Daniel Pineault on DEV HUT and Nigel Heffernan on this site).  Just remember to make the folder that you want to trust **FIRST**, then edit the registry to trust it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the next function to add files in Trusted Locations. I am using it in VBA Corel Draw, to add files used in Excel automation:

```
Private Function CreatePathInTrLoc(ByVal sPath As String, ByVal sDescription As String, Optional boolReplace As Boolean)
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001, sAppExe As String = "excel.exe", sApp As String = "Excel"
    Dim oRegistry As Object, sAppVer As String, sParentKey As String, bAlreadyExists As Boolean
    Dim arrChildKeys As Variant, sChildKey As Variant, sValue As String, sNewKey As String
    Dim iLocCounter As Long, strReplace As String, sExtPath As String
    
    Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    sAppVer = GetAppVersion(sAppExe)                  '   Returns: 12.0.6720.5000
    sAppVer = Left(sAppVer, InStr(sAppVer, ".") - 1) & "." & Mid(sAppVer, InStr(sAppVer, ".") + 1, 1)
    
    sParentKey = "Software\Microsoft\Office\" & sAppVer & "\" & sApp & "\Security\Trusted Locations"
    
    iLocCounter = 0
    oRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sParentKey, arrChildKeys
    For Each sChildKey In arrChildKeys
        oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sParentKey & "\" & sChildKey, "Description", sValue
        If sValue = sDescription Then
            If boolReplace Then
                oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sParentKey & "\" & sChildKey, "Path", sExtPath
                If sExtPath <> sPath Then
                    oRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sParentKey & "\" & sChildKey
                    strReplace = sChildKey
                    GoTo OverDeleteKey
                Else
                    bAlreadyExists = True
                End If
            Else
                bAlreadyExists = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If CInt(Mid(sChildKey, 9)) > iLocCounter Then
            iLocCounter = CInt(Mid(sChildKey, 9))
        End If
    Next
OverDeleteKey:
    
    If Not bAlreadyExists Then
        sNewKey = sParentKey & IIf(strReplace <> "", "\" & strReplace, "\Location" & CStr(iLocCounter + 1))
        
        oRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey
        oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "Path", sPath
        oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "Description", sDescription
        oRegistry.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "AllowSubFolders", 1
        Debug.Print "Path """ & sPath & """ added in Trusted Locations."
    Else
        Debug.Print "Path """ & sPath & """ already exists..."
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetAppVersion(sAppExe As String) As String 'extract application version
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    Dim oRegistry As Object, oFSO As Object, sKey As String, sValue As String

    Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/default:StdRegProv")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sKey = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths"

    oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKey & "\" & sAppExe, "", sValue
    GetAppVersion = oFSO.GetFileVersion(sValue)

    Set oFSO = Nothing: Set oRegistry = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Many Thanks, tested ok in excel (just changing this line: `sAppVer = Application.Version` ). But i'm not able to set `AllowSubFolders`. This is my not working try: `oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "AllowSubFolders", 1`

Comment: @robertocm Ups... I can see now that I forgot to also place the function returning application version. Updated the above answer with the function in discussion. Which registry key do you want modifying? Please, write it here **in clear** and I will try helping with the code. I can check by myself, but it would be easier/faster to have it if you already know it... I mean, do you know that adding such a key it will work for subfolders, too? I know that the key exists only for a **specific location** (Location 0 to x), not in the root key which the code deals to...

Comment: I see this in registry: Name: AllowSubfolders, Type: REG_DWORD Values (0=No; 1=Yes), better explained here https://ss64.com/access/syntax-trusted.html (sorry is above my level)

Comment: @robertocm You should create a **`REG_DWORD`** key, not `REG_SZ` as already creating... I will adapt the code to also create such a key with its `1` value... **Adapted**. Please, test it and send some feedback.